# JIRA 4.1.1 disable user notification

Tags: jira

We are running JIRA 4.1.1 and had an employee who moved elsewhere in the company. We still need his issues in JIRA so we can't completely removed him. Is there anyway to make it so he won't still receive emails/notifications?

I need a solution other than changing the email to an unused or invalid email address, because this will start eating up log space in JIRA

Thanks.

Comment: hmm, Ok. so do you have some code to share? –

Comment: There is no code, we are running the application and I am looking for a way within the application to disable notifications for specific users

Comment: Ok understood. a check says it's doable, yes - https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/53576/switching-off-notification-email-for-a-particular-user

Comment: I need to be able to do it with out setting it as an invalid or unused email address as the question states. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If he moved to another role, his tasks and responsibilities should have been taken over by someone else.
Make a bulk edit and assign that new user to the given issues. 
With bulk edit, you can change reporter also.